# HP 8300 CMT only turns on sometimes

Tags: boot, memory, graphics-card, motherboard, power-supply

My HP 8300 with an

- i5 3570
- 8 GB RAM
- EVGA 600W PSU
- GTX 1060

does not turn on consistently. If I press the button then the fans run for only 1 second or so and nothing happens. Sometimes (maybe 1 out of 20 times) it turns on and everything works smoothly.

Following measures have been already tried:

- Replacing CMOS battery
- Replacing Motherboard (both used)
- Trying out different slots and combination of RAM
- Changing PSU
- Taking out the motherboard on cardboard and then starting
- Run with and without GTX 1060
- Get rid of charge before turning on PC
- Unplug everything and "get rid of remaining electricity" by pressing power button

I have the (uneducated guess) suspicion that something shorts out since sometimes it helps when I unplug the PSU and start from fresh. But even this is not consistent.

Do you guys have any other suggestion?

Comment: You tried everything obvious. Its too new for capasitor plague but visually inspecting the capasitors for bloating would be worth trying.

Comment: Ok, will do as soon as I get home!
Any other suggestions will also be very appreciated!

Comment: I've got nothing. You have literally tried everything I would.